# Deployment Symfony 6

Tags: symfony6

For a few days I have been stuck on the problem of switching a Symfony 6 project to prod.
I constantly get an error message about writing to php://stderr. I have replaced the path in config/packages/monolog.yaml and put "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log" there but nothing is done. I have the impression that this file is ignored in prod. Of course, I created myself a prod config/packages folder to put another monolog.yaml there but still nothing happens.
Question: Why is the var/log/prod.log file not created? Why in the tutorials sometimes we talk about config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml and sometimes just config/packages/monolog.yaml. Symfony is really complicated at the deployment level and I wonder if I chose the Framework correctly. We can't even display the detailed errors.

config monolog.yaml gives no result

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.